# Export HTML table to Excel not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

We need to export HTML table to Excel. It works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox but not on Internet Explorer 11 (does not export to Excel) even though I don't see an error in console of Developers tools.

Version: 11.0.9600.17959 Update version: 11.0.22

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/AbuSufyan/t5c1o6fw/9/'
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You should add the actual code in addition to posting the fiddle - that could be gone tomorrow, rendering this question useless

Comment: This tells you what the problem is: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri  Note the restrictions on data URI's in IE